# How to programmatically ad a character to a string in R

Tags: r, iteration, transformation, programmatically-created, chron

I apologize in advance if this has been posted elsewhere. I am new to R, and I am having trouble manipulating a dataframe.

I have a column in my dataframe that contains times in the format of hh mm ss. However, some values only have a single "0" in the hh place (for example, "0:01:30" or "0:20:30").

I am trying to use the chron package to convert these into a time object so that I can find  the min, max, and mean time durations, but I need to add a zero to the hours column before I do so. What would be the best way to do this in R? Since some values in the column don't need to have a zero added, what would be the best way to iterate through each value and check for a specific condition?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `times(c("0:01:30", "0:20:30"))` works without adding a 0.

Comment: I went back and tried again, and I realized my error wasn't with the single zero at the end, but instead because some values were well over 24 hours. I'm trying to find a way to make this a time or numeric object so that I can find the average time duration. Would I need to find another package?

Comment: Try `library(lubridate); mean(as.duration(hms(c("30:01:30", "0:20:30"))))`

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. It gave me a parse error with this message: “Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs”. the values that are over 24 hours are quite large (for example, "142:30:00" and "123:21:00"). The times() function set these to NA. If those are the issue, would I have to create my own function to manipulate those?

Comment: I was not suggesting that this be used with `times`.  It returns the number of seconds.  If you want to display this as a lubridate period object use `as.period(as.duration(mean(as.duration(hms(c("142:30:00", "123:21:00"))))))`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can deal with that directly via the `chron` package as suggested in the comments.

Otherwise a simple if else statement should do the job. Assuming `t` is your column and `dat` your dataframe, and the issue happens only in the hh part(otherwise add more conditions):

```
library(dplyr)
dat$t1 <- if_else(nchar(dat$t)==7, paste0(0,dat$t), dat$t)
```